Opening SEB exam when Chrome Remote desktop is running
Background: I created an SEB (Safe Exam Browser) exam which would go into Kiosk mode (which basically blocks everything on my desktop), and let me access only the apps I allowed it to open (in this case, its a chrome browser, which has every other site blocked via an extension, except the ones related to the stuff I need). I use Firefox as my default browser, so I could keep chrome for this purpose. So whenever I get to do my work, I open the exam file, which lets me access only the stuff I need and nothing more.
I did this mainly because of my distractions, so this method blocks everything out, except for the stuff related to my work.
The problem: I recently am working on how I would make my computer accessible remotely, whenever I'll be outside. So for this I was using Chrome Remote Desktop, which made me install a software bundle, including remoting_host.exe .
However, this is now interfering with my SEB exam. My SEB exam would not open, and it shows the following error:

The application listed below need to be terminated before a new
session can be started. Would you like to automatically terminate them
now?
WARNING: Any  unsaved application data might be lost!
remoting_host.exe

Clicking on Yes, shows the following:

The applications listed below could not be terminated! Please
terminate them manually and try again...
remoting_host.exe

and then SEB terminates.
I tried everthing, from allowing every exe programs in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome Remote Desktop\130.0.6723.14 folder (including remoting_host.exe), to enabling Allow remote session/screen sharing option in SEB configuration, but nothing seems to work. I tried searching this online, but nowhere the answer seems to be satisfactory.
TL;DR: How can I make my SEB exam open even when Chrome Remote desktop is running in the background?
Edit:  I am still looking for an answer. I know it is a very specific use case, which is why I am here. I am also continuing my own research on this, but I am truly at a dead end. I tried everything, trying out other browsers specifically for chrome remote desktop, making exceptions in SEB itself. For what i understood, it maybe hard coded in the software. Is there any way to edit the SEB software itself, if yes, I really need help in that, because I have no idea on how to edit binary executables. This being such a specific use case, I could not get the solution anywhere on the web. Thank again to anyone who stops by.
Edit 2: Sorry again for this edit, but I wanted to let everyone know I am still looking for an answer. I have spent way too much time on this topic, and the answers I got varies from vaguely written documentations, to SourceForge forums, where the developers himself puts up fake promises for updates (which I refuse to believe there has been any on this software since its launch). I would really appreciate if anybody even tries to help me here. If you feel, this is not the reight place for this question, feel free to let me know. Cheers!

I think a simple way to get around this would be not to run the remote desktop on the machine. I use a cheap USB video capture card to work on headless machines - but there's devices like the PiKVM, nanoKVM and others that'll let you plug in a HDMI and USB port from the machine and access it via a web interface. That should give you the ability to work remotely on a machine without interference from/with software that's monitoring other processes.

sounds great...Thanks for the answer !...could have upvoted, but I don't have the 15 rep minimum for that. :P
